# How to get all points positions of line renderer in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get all points positions in the line of line renderer ,i need this points positions because i want to draw a line by line renderer and then let a ball move on this line so i want to move this ball using line's points position to let the ball move on this line after drawing it

and this is my code to draw a line using line renderer

```
public LineRenderer lineRend;
public EdgeCollider2D edgeColl;

List <Vector2> points;

public void Update_line(Vector2 mouse_pos)
{
    if (points == null)
    {
        points = new List<Vector2> ();

        set_point(mouse_pos);

        return;
    }

    if (Vector2.Distance(points[points.Count - 1], mouse_pos) > .1f)
    {
        set_point(mouse_pos);
    }

}

void set_point(Vector2 point)
{
    points.Add(point);

    lineRend.positionCount = points.Count;
    lineRend.SetPosition(points.Count - 1, point);

    if (points.Count > 1)
    {
        edgeColl.points = points.ToArray();
    }
}
```

}

And the below image illustrates what i want to do in my game 
the ball which is in the bottom of the image i want it to move on the drawn line

[The illustration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psRAk.png)

so what i have to do this by code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
lineRend.GetPositions(out Vector3[] allPoints);
```

`GetPositions` returns all the points on a line renderer in the out variable. Its an array of `Vector3`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html